# How to iterate over array nested in object as props

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON file that I'm parsing for data but I am trying to map a subarray (nested in an object). However, I am getting an error sayin that the array is not iterable. I logged the array to the console where it prints the array but when I check its type it says "object".

Here is my code:

```
export default function Projects({ children, ...props }) {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={styles.text}>
          <p>{props.description}</p>
          <ul>
            {props.features.map((feature) => (
              <li>{feature}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Netflix Clone",
    "img": "/netflix-clone.jpg",
    "direction": "row",
    "description": "This project is a minimalistic Netflix clone utilising Firefox for storage and authorisation. It utilises Styled Components for styling, compound components, large-scale React architecture, and custom hooks.",
    "features": [
      "React",
      "Styled Components",
      "Compound components",
      "Large-Scale React Architecture",
      "Firebase (Firestore & Auth)",
      "Functional components",
      "Firebase (Firestore & Auth)",
      "Custom hooks"
    ]
  },
]
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: If you are loading the data async then I assume on initial render the data is undefined, you need to make sure your views account for this by either showing loading animations or nothing until the data has loaded. you could try using `!!props.features && props.features.map()` (`map()` should still include your original code).

Comment: Cheers Jacob, post this as an answer (as it worked) and I'll tick it :)

Comment: Can you provide a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? How is the data being passed as prop? How do you guard against potentially unavailable (yet) data?

Comment: Can you show us how you are passing props to `Projects`? Also, can show what `console.log(props)` prints in `Projects` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading data async the initial renders of your components will not have access to the data (the data will be `undefined`).

Your components should be coded to cope with this situation by displaying a different view, such as loading animations.

This could be achieved by simply checking if `props.features` is defined before rendering out your components:

```
export default function Projects({ children, ...props }) {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={styles.text}>
          <p>{props.description}</p>
          <ul>
            {
                /** Conditionally show only when props.features has a truthy value **/
                !!props.features && props.features.map((feature) => (
                    <li>{feature}</li>
                ))
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To show another component / text while the data is loading you could use a ternary statement:

```
export default function Projects({ children, ...props }) {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={styles.text}>
          <p>{props.description}</p>
          <ul>
            {
                /** Ternary statement to show components when props.features is a truthy value 
                    or loading when a falsy value **/
                props.features ? 
                    props.features.map((feature) => (
                        <li>{feature}</li>
                    )) :
                    "Loading..."
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On initial render, there is no data yet in features. Use condition like this ->

```
props && props.features && props.features.map((feature) => (
          <li>{feature}</li>
        ))}
```

Comment: `props` will always be defined in a react component (provided it is *actually* defined to have one), the first condition is superfluous.